# Call before hook once for test with a set of examples in Cucumber

Tags: cucumber

I'm trying to run a scenario with Cucumber that is using a before hook to load a dataset. My problem is the Scenario has a set of examples and the before step is called before every example, meaning I'm getting stopped at the start of the second example because of DatabaseUnitExceptions.

Is there some way to only call the before hook once for the whole scenario and not for each example?

Cheers

Comment: Which Cucumber version are you using in which language? Please share the code you are using.

Comment: Note that `Scenario Outline` is just a way to easily define multiple scenarios. There is no way curre tly to execute a hook only in one of these scenarios. You should probably make your hook more robust/idempotent.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Gaël; each example under a scenario outline is a scenario. So Cucumber will run the @Before hook before each scenario / example. (Scenario and example being synonyms to Cucumber).

If you want to run a hook before *all* scenarios, have a look at `@BeforeAll`. Please refer to the [Cucumber documentation on hooks.](https://docs.cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#hooks)